# Well-definedness of rational exponents?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I am a little bit confused witht the definition of rational exponents. I believe that the definition of $a^{\frac pq}$ is $\sqrt[q]{a}^p.$ However, $\dfrac 26 = \dfrac 13$, yet $-1^{2/6}$ is undefined (or imaginary?), while $-1^{1/3}=-1.$ How do we resolve this situation?

Comment: $a^{p/q}=(a^p)^{1/q}$ is only well defined for $a>0$ :)

Comment: @C.Brendel Ah haha

Comment: For $a<0$ you'd have to tap into complex numbers, unfortunately rational exponents aren't well defined but rather yield a whole "class" of reasonable answers. Like taking the complex logarithm where one could say: $$\log(1)=2\pi\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: You may learn [Complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_analysis)